# Display taxonomies for custom post type

Tags: custom-taxonomy

I have a custom post type as `Products` with custom taxonomies `product-year` `product-cat` and `product-country`

I want to create a table like below but I am not sure how to populate the code.

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution, that may guide you to desired result.

```
$years = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product-year',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ) );

    $cats = get_terms( array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
        'hide_empty' => true,
    ) );

if ( ! empty( $years ) && ! is_wp_error( $years ) ){
    foreach ( $years as $year ) {
        echo '<strong>'.$year->name.'</strong>';
        if ( ! empty( $cats ) && ! is_wp_error( $cats ) ){
            foreach ( $cats as $cat ) {
                echo '<strong>'.$cat->name.'</strong>';
                $args = array(
                            'post_type' => 'Products',
                            'tax_query' => array(
                                'relation' => 'AND',
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product-year',
                                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'    => array( $year->term_id ),
                                    ),
                                array(
                                    'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
                                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                                    'terms'    => array( $cat->term_id ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        );
                $query = new WP_Query( $args );
                if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                    echo '<table>';
                    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                        $query->the_post();

                        $countries = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product-country' );

                        if ( $countries && ! is_wp_error( $countries ) ) : 

                              $countries_links = array();

                              foreach ( $countries as $country ) {
                                  $countries_links[] = $country->name;
                               }

                              $countries_names = join( ", ", $countries_links );
                        }
                        echo '<tr><td>' . get_the_title( ) . '</td>'.'<td>' . $countries_names . '</td></tr>'  ;
                    }
                    echo '</table>';

                    // Restore original Post Data
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please take care of any typo if any.

Comment: Hello @QaisarFeroz, thanks for your effort to help me out. I am receiving an error in this line: as  `Array to string conversion` in `echo '<tr><td>' . get_the_title( $query->post->ID ) . '</td>'.'<td>' . get_the_terms( $query->post->ID,'product-country' ) . '</td></tr>'  ;`

Comment: I have updated the answer.